# What is wrong with my version of strchr?

Tags: c, pointers, strchr

My assignment is to write my own version of strchr, yet it doesn't seem to work. Any advice would be much appreciated.
Here it is:

```
char *strchr (const char *s, int c) //we are looking for c on the string s
{

    int dog; //This is the index on the string, initialized as 0
    dog = 0;
    int point; //this is the pointer to the location given by the index
    point = &s[dog];
    while ((s[dog] != c) && (s[dog] != '\0')) { //it keeps adding to dog until it stumbles upon either c or '\0'
            dog++;
            }
    if (s[dog]==c) {
            return point; //at this point, if this value is equal to c it returns the pointer to that location
            }
    else {
            return NULL; //if not, this means that c is not on the string
            }
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" - please be more descriptive.

Comment: Well, one problem is that you name a variable `dog` for no particular reason. A second seems to be that you mix pointers and integers.

Comment: `point` is not a pointer type, so it cannot hold a pointer. This code should not even compile. Moreover, `int` is not an appropriate type for an offset in a string.

Comment: @larsmans: Maybe it's to be analogous to `cat` in OP's implementation of `strcat`...? :-)

Answer (score 4):

You return "point" which was originally initialized to beginning of string and not moved since then. You don't need that variable at all, but could simply return &s[dog] (although I would prefer something more descriptive than dog as a variable name).

In fact you would survive with something as simple as this:

```
while (*s != c && *s)
    ++s;

return (*s == c) ? s : NULL;
```

Comment: +1 The `if` in the return part could be replaced with a conditional operator for even better compactness.

Comment: +1, though there is a cast missing from this implementation (see my comment to @wabepper's answer).

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to store an address into `point` but it's an int-variable. You should do something like this:

```
char *strchr(char *s, char c) {
    int pos = 0;
    while (s[pos] != c && s[pos] != '\0')
        pos++;
    if (s[pos] == c)
        return &s[pos];
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

By the way: `s` should be `char *` not `const char *` because your returning an pointer to a`char`, and that wouldn't be a good style ;) (or return `const char *`)

Comment: The C standard mandates that `strchr` takes `const` pointer but returns a mutable one into the same buffer. So a compliant pure-C implementation has to cast the `const` away.

Comment: You can also increment the pointer directly like this: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1081902/

Comment: You should also use type `size_t` for `pos` rather than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int point;
```

This is not the declaration of a pointer, here is how to declare a pointer to an `int`:

```
int *bla;
```

In your case `&s[dog]` is a pointer to a `const char`, so you want to declare `point` this way:

```
 const char *point;
```

And as others pointed out, you are actually ignoring this pointer in your function afterwards.

Comment: That's true, but the OP doesn't actually want an `int` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code

```
int point; //this is the pointer to the location given by the index
point = &s[dog];
```

you are trying to convert a pointer to char to an `int`, when

```
char* point = &s[dog];
```

is what you want. You should have seen this from the return type of your function. You want to return a `char*` but you return an `int` (your variable `point`) or NULL. As you never actually change `point`, you are actually returning the address of the first character in your array, so your code is not working as you would like anyway.
If you insist on this you would be better using

```
char* point = &s[dog];
while ((*point != c) && (*point != '\0')) {          
   ++point;
}
return (*point == c) ? point : NULL;
```

But here it looks like you still have a conceptual problem as you want to compare a `char` with an `int`. You should work out if you need an `int` array or a `char` array. If you want a `char` array, change your input argument `c` to be of type `char`.